# How to use eigenvector for image compression?

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

Let's say I have a N*D data of N images and D dimensions (256=16*16) of each image.

I have use eig in matlab to calculate the 256*256 eigenvector matrix with each colunm representing eigenvector.

Now I have to compress images using this information using 10, 20, 80, 100 eigendigits from my eigenvector. How to do this projection in matlab.

Secondly, once I do this projection I need to recontruct each sample image back into 1*256 row. How to achieve this after compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to read about PCA. Here is a very nice explanation.

Document: Principal Component Analysis from Mark Richardson

In there, you have the technical detail and the application to image.

Comment: Unfortunately, just four monthes later the paper is no more available...

Comment: True, I write the title.